# clang compiler does not support -pg

Tags: profile, clang

I've been porting over a project from g++ to clang.

Clang;s compiler claims to not support -pg ... so no gprofile? What's the expected way to profile under clang? Valgrind & oprofile? Or is there some new llvm specific tool?

Comment: Clang does not support C++ at this time. It's going to invoke g++ behind the scenes.